# QT6 designer.exe (apparently) doesn't launch (on Windows-10)

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyqt6

Running C:\Programs\Python311\Lib\site-packages\qt6_applications\Qt\bin\designer.exe does nothing. I also tried BASH$ pyqt6-tools designer and BASH$ pyside6-designer in VS-Code. All three attempts do nothing - no complaints, no error messages, no feedback whatsoever.  I have WSL(2) installed, so I also tried running that  designer.exe from the WSL shell - it doesn't crash, but doesn't do anything either.

Having also installed PySide6 via WSL's python, I have a ~/.local/bin with a bunch of pyside6 tools, including pyside6-designer, so I ran that from WSL's Bourne shell, but it bombs out complaining that it needs libxkbcommon.so.0 (which does not exist anywhere in my WSL) nor does https://www.x.org/releases/individual/lib/ list a libxkbcommon that one could get. Suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand. You claim that you're using WSL, so the Designer executable certainly is *not* a `exe` file (which is a *windows binary*), and, as far as I know (and as logic would suggest), you cannot directly launch a Linux executable from a standard Windows command prompt. Also: what "details" are you referring to? How did you install PyQt and its tools?

Comment: Details are seen as the first paragraph of a post at creation time.  I'm pushing all possible buttons, thus launching Windows executables from WSL and vice versa.  PySide6-designer (in that long Windows directory) was created under Windows' Python3.11.  The .local/bin one was created in WSL's Python3.11